# ng-repeat won't work in modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I'm trying to get a modal to ng-repeat an array of objects and it won't show up at all. 
I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong but hoping for help as to getting the ng-repeat to work!

```
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
        <h4>Transfer Funds</h4>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">
                                eGift Cards
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="trans in gctrans.Items | filter: cardSearch">
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <strong>{{getCustomerName(trans)}}</strong>
                                <strong>{{getCustomerCardNumber(trans)}}</strong>
                                <small>{{getCustomerPhone(trans) | tel}}<br /></small>
                                <small> {{getCustomerEmail(trans)}}<br /></small>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<br />
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="confirmTransfer(trans)">Next</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put your Angular code too ?

Comment: Are you sure the modal has anything to do with it?  Have you tried the view outside of a modal?

Comment: Have you tried removing the filter?

Comment: Please post the corresponding controller code. Or even better, provide a plunkr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the two most likely things that would be causing this are model not existing in scope and filter causing unexpected behavior. The first to try would be seeing if the `gctrans.Items` is available in the scope of the modal. Try adding `{{gctrans}}` in the modal and see if any data is there, like:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   raw data: {{gctrans}}
   <table class="table">
```

second, if there is data try removing the filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="trans in gctrans.Items">
```

and one more thing to try, if the data is good and the filter is not unexpectedly removing items, you might not be selecting anything inside of the repeat. Try just outputting the item

```
<tr ng-repeat="trans in gctrans.Items">
  <td class="text-center">
    <strong>{{trans}}</strong>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for the input. I figured out what I had done wrong in the controller (hadn't declared gctrans in the modal function). 
Make sure all your stuff is declared in functions as well if you're using modals and ng-repeat!

Comment: nice, glad I could help! It seemed most likely that `gctrans.Items` wasn't available in the scope of the modal, as I suggested. Can you accept my answer then? :)

Comment: I did, sorry I've never closed questions out before! Thank you so much!

Comment: ah, no worries! way to go accepting your first finished SO answer :)